# I'm getting "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" when visiting Meta SO chat

Tags: support, bug, chat, meta

I am seeing a very strange issue on the [Meta Stackoverflow Chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/). Stack Overflow's chat is working for me fine, this is just the *Meta*'s chat that doesn't work.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

> [image]

Comment: Are you talking about Stack Overflow or **Meta** Stack Overflow?

Comment: Meta Stack Overflow chat

Comment: It's working fine for me.

Comment: I just tested and still have same issue in all the browsers

Comment: Works fine here: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta

Comment: @EdCottrell You are right but here it showing error http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/. When I am simply clicking Stack Exchange above and it gives me popup then I click on the chat then it giving me error

Comment: @Williams That link goes to http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/, which is also working for me.

Comment: @AaronBrager but not for me

Comment: Do you have custom userscripts working to create other **problemz**?

Comment: No I do not have, I tried with different browsers and having same problem

Comment: ... and Who downvoted this question. This is not bad question afaik

Comment: if you do `ping chat.meta.stackoverflow.com` using whatever you are using what returns?

Comment: @Braiam See here http://pastebin.com/zeqzsYtM

Comment: Also, I see you are not logged in, could you try to log in?

Comment: No, you are wrong, I am already logged in and see here one more bug http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222172/bug-in-the-meta-stack-overflow-chat, chat opening only when I click on this http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta but not on http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Heh, I bet is some caching going on.

Comment: No I have even uninstall the browser and cleared the all the history, data, cache and having same issue, any solution? and Stackoverflow chat is working very good in my case but not meta chat

Comment: Did you encounter this problem before? Or, this is your first time accessing Meta chat? Is there a possibility like cookie-blocking, or firewall problem?

Comment: @AndrewT. This is the first time, I am seeing this issue today. There is no firewall or cookie blocking because stackoverflow chat is already working correctly

Comment: @Williams clear browser cache or open cmd ipconfig/flushdns

Comment: Everyone: The chat works for us. That's been said enough times. You can stop commenting about that. Williams is experiencing his own issue; we can still deal with that.

Comment: @Williams Chill out and relax; we know it's not working for you but people will come in and comment when it's working for them nevertheless. Something weird is going on here and maybe a developer will ask what's going on sooner or later.

Comment: @Williams bugs happen, please be patient. If it bothers you so much send direct email to team@stackexchange.com say you can't chat on Meta, and they will look into it. Until then, whatever issues you want to discuss in chat you can also discuss here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I can not discuss on chat because it is not working in my case but I will try to contact with stackexchange team soon. thanks :)