# Bug in the Meta Stack Overflow chat

Tags: bug, chat, meta

I am just created the account on the meta stackoverflow. I have logged into the meta stackoverflow, When I clicked on this http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta then it is asking to me to login again. I tried it again then I again did login but When I go to same on the chat then showing to me to login again. So Ultimately I am not able to get logged in the chat.

Guys it seems very weird to me, how a such big platform behaving like buggy

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: If you retry to go in chat what next time you can see? same issue or logged in?

Comment: I am seeing same thing this http://i.stack.imgur.com/SQfrl.png I tried this four times and having same issue

Comment: Give it some time, also can you login to other chat room, not in Meta?

Comment: I am waiting this for last 4 hours and I am able to logged in the Stack Overflow Android room, you can see me here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android